# Слайдер задерживает загрузку страницы

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

Я разработал сайт с большим количеством слайдеров owlCarousel.

Заметил, что в процессе загрузки главной страницы, слайдер в третьем секшене задерживает показ остального контента.

[www.instale.co.il](https://www.instale.co.il/)

Подгружать его динамично через ajax не вариант.

Каким образом можно решить этот вопрос не навредив поисковой оптимизации сайта?

Comment: У меня всё подгружается нормально. Но очень медленно происходит само переключение между вкладками

Comment: У меня тоже быстро загружается